# How to exclude regex selection if a word stands before?

Tags: python, regex

This regex `he | she` selects `he` or `she` (with one space before and after):

```
how he just he just
when she just she just
```

Can I exclude selection if a word `how` or `when` stands before? I mean select only second column in the example above.

https://regex101.com/r/pEGLD2/2

Comment: Usually, a negative lookbehind does this job. If you have trouble with that, please edit the question with your current regex.

Comment: `\w*(?<!how) he | she ` It's not selecting what I ask in the question.

Comment: Certainly, you do not have any word chars  there, you do not need `\w*`. Besides, after `how` and `when` you havbe a space. You should account for that in the lookbehind. Also, if you want to apply one or a series of lookbehinds to two or more alternatives, group them.

Comment: Just an example: https://regex101.com/r/6faQIi/1